# Hosting Servicestack with .net Core

Tags: servicestack

My solution has two project: 
Lib project => .Net standard 2.0, with TestApp class implement AppHostBase

Host project => .Net Core 2.0. With program class like below:

```
var listeningOn = args.Length == 0 ? "http://*:1337/" : args[0];
        var appHost = new TestApp();

        appHost.Start(listeningOn);
        Console.WriteLine("AppHost Created at {0}, listening on {1}",
            DateTime.Now, listeningOn);

        Console.ReadKey();
```

When I try to run it has an exception: 
System.NotImplementedException: 'Start(listeningAtUrlBase) is not supported by this AppHost'

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

We recommend starting from one of the [.NET Core Project Templates](http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#new-net-core-20-project-templates) which shows the proper way to configure ServiceStack in a .NET Core project, e.g. you can create a [minimal .NET Core SelfHost](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/selfhost) with:

```
$ dotnet tool install -g web

$ web new selfhost ProjectName
```

If you're creating an [empty ASP.NET Core Web App](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/web) you should instead use:

```
$ web new web ProjectName
```

The recommended way to configure ServiceStack is to [register your AppHost with .NET Core's pipeline](http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#net-core-startup) like any other .NET Core middleware:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost { 
        AppSettings = new NetCoreAppSettings(Configuration)
    }); 
}
```

This is the recommended way to integrate ServiceStack with your .NET Core App which requires your `AppHost` to [inherit from `AppHostBase`](http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#net-core-apphost-integration):

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase { ... }
```

When inheriting from `AppHostBase` you're never calling `.Start()` on ServiceStack's AppHost, it's instead started as a [normal .NET Core App using WebHostBuilder](http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#binding-to-net-core).

#### [AppSelfHostBase Source-compatible Self-Host](http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#appselfhostbase-source-compatible-self-host)

To support enabling source-code compatible AppHost for .NET Core and .NET Framework Integration Tests your AppHost can inherit `AppSelfHostBase` in the **ServiceStack.Kestrel** NuGet package which is started like a [normal ServiceStack Self AppHost](https://github.com/NetFrameworkTemplates/vue-spa-netfx/blob/master/MyApp.Tests/IntegrationTest.cs), but as this offers less flexibility in configuring your .NET Core App, it's the less recommended configuration.